# Using whole space of pdf file

Tags: pdf, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, prawn, prawnto

I am using prawn to create pdf file but it always leaves some spaces/margins around the page. Can't we use whole space of the pdf file not leaving any margins around?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the page bounds ?

The general space that is consumed on the page can be shown by the example code:

```
require 'prawn/core'
require 'prawn/layout'

Prawn::Document.generate('padded_box.pdf') do
  stroke_bounds
  text "Margin box"
  padded_box(25) do
    stroke_bounds
    text "Bounding box padded by 25 on all sides from the margins"
    padded_box(50) do
      stroke_bounds
      text "Bounding box padded by 50 on all sides from the parent bounds"
    end
  end
end
```

This will draw the bounds of the page showing the margin.  There is a gap, which is the margins typically defined for the printing area

Comment: I think there isn't a way to do that. We can't use whole pdf page space.

Comment: The code sample was to show the margin spacing that are the defaults within prawn.

Comment: Okay its again padding_box and bounding_box